# How to differentiate magnetite from metallic iron?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, metal, metallurgy, identification

Both metallic iron and magnetite, $\ce{Fe3O4}$, are magnetic. Now, iron is grey in color, whereas hematite is black, so that they can be distinguished visually.
Now, I have a powdery mixture of iron/magnetite and lighter grains so that the mixture appears grey, making visual differentiating a bit tricky. I assumed it was iron, but someone else claimed it could also be magnetite, and now I'm not sure.

Is there a really easy way to be sure what I am dealing with? I don't want to do an XRD just for this.

Comment: Hematite is red.

Comment: oh my goodness, I meant magnetite! changing it now

Comment: Do the XRD. Unless you have to pay for it or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the methods that come to mind:

1. [LIBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser-induced_breakdown_spectroscopy)
2. [XRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_fluorescence)
3. [Streak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streak_(mineralogy)) color. When scratching on unglazed porcelain, magnetite leaves charcoal-black traces, whereas iron leaves shiny steel-gray streaks. Having a powdery mixture this test can be tricky, unless there are reasonably big shards left. Alternatively, one can try to assemble a bulky piece by gluing the powder together with silicate adhesive or cyanoacrylate (as paracetamol suggested in the comments, "*rubbing some of the mysterious powder between two shards of porcelain*" can also do).
4. Compare density of your sample with $\rho(\ce{Fe}) = \pu{7.874 g cm-3}$, $\rho(\ce{Fe3O4}) = \pu{4.9 .. 5.2 g cm-3}$ and, assuming this mechanical mixture consists of iron and magnetite *exclusively*, calculate the percentage of each phase.

Magnetite in its mineral form often contains $\ce{(Fe,Mg)O}$, $\ce{TiO2}$ and isomorphous impurities of $\ce{Mn}$, rarely $\ce{Cr}$, $\ce{V}$; therefore physical methods of analysis (1, 2) are more preferable. Due to the same reason I'm not suggesting treatment with $\ce{HCl}$ and other methods based on chemical transformations as primary for this analysis.

Comment: "*Alternatively, one can try to assemble a bulky piece by gluing the powder together with silicate adhesive or cyanoacrylate.*" That's a *very* novel method :D

Comment: @paracetamol Well, when means are limited, one must improvise. Colorless adhesive that doesn't change composition of phases shouldn't influence the outcome, and if a single phase is dominating, then it will become clear quite fast. But again, it depends on the grain size -- maybe this gluing thing isn't necessary.

Comment: How about rubbing some of the mysterious powder between two shards of porcelain? A little messier, maybe...